# Merging two pandas dataframes based on a DateTime column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, merge

The two columns from the two dataframes might have a little offset in time, maybe seconds or maybe a few minutes, how do I merge these columns when there is this time offset?

Comment: Sample data, expected output and your own attempt would be appreciated. See [ask] a question with a [mcve] and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I think you need `merge_asof`